# PHP preg_match_all cutting out text elements

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

Got a question.

I have a HTML string that I have imported into PHP. `file_get_contents`.
What I want to do is to cut out some strings at the hand of tags like *{{* or *[tagname]* and *[/tagname]*

And then return them in an array so I can process them.
For example :

**{{header.tpl}}** to have PHP load the **header.tpl** file and replace **{{header.tpl}}** with its contents.

I THINK that regex is the way to go. But that's exactly where my weak spot is. I have tried but to no avail.

I got as far as the following code:

```
<?php

$text = '
            Hi this is a text<br />
            [@title]
            <br />
            {{header.tpl}}
            <br /><a href="#">link</a>{{menu.tpl}}<br />
            <hr/>
            <h1>[@subtitle]</h1>
            [@content]
            {submenu}
                {itemactive}<a href="#"><strong>[@link]</strong></a>{/itemactive}
                {itema}<a href="#">[@link]</a>{/item}
            {/submenu}

            ';


$pattern = '^\{{.*}}^';

preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

It gives some results though.

:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{header.tpl}}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{menu.tpl}}
        )

)
```

Is this what I want? 
No but.... **close!**
Because when I am using the now nicely formatted `$text` string as one long string.

Like :

```
$text = 'Hi this is a text<br />[@title]<br />{{header.tpl}}<br /><a href="#">link</a>{{menu.tpl}}<br /><hr/><h1>[@subtitle]</h1>[@content]';
```

It goes wrong!

The result will become:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {{header.tpl}}<br /><a href="#">link</a>{{menu.tpl}}
        )

)
```

And even then I want the result to be just like the one above!
Then the second problem...

I think I should use the same option for getting the *submenu*.
Something like :

```
$pattern = '^\{submenu}.*{/submenu}^';
```

But strangely that does not work. :-(
And all that I get is:

```
    Array
(
)
```

Would anyone be able to tell me what I am doing wrong?

TIAD!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where close.

The **problem** with `^\{{.*}}^`

- `.*` is greedy and would match anything till the next `}}` change that to a non greedy `.*?` or as in the below regex.

A **better** regex would be

```
\{\{[^}]+}}
```

Example : http://regex101.com/r/gF4jZ6/1

- `\{\{` matches the `{{`
- `[^}]+` matches anything other than a `}`
- `}}` matches `}}`

Will give an output as

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => {{header.tpl}} ) [1] => Array ( [0] => {{menu.tpl}} ) )
```

**Note** for differnece between the two regexes see [this link](http://regex101.com/r/gF4jZ6/2) also

Now inoder to match  submenu, just add an `s` flag so that the `.` matches new line as well

```
$pattern = '/\{submenu}.*?{\/submenu}/s';
```

Comment: Changing `$pattern = '^\{{.*}}^';` into  : `$pattern = '^\{{.*?}}^';` Did work!

`\{\{[^}]+}}` didn't.
It gave me the warning :
_italic_Warning: preg_match_all(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash_italic_

And there my limited understanding starts playing on me again...

Comment: @AlexHakkenberg glad to hear i helped :)